# Jest tests not found

Tags: gitlab, jestjs, gitlab-ci

I have the following output in a gitlab job:

```
yarn run v1.15.2
$ jest --verbose
No tests found
In /path/to/my/project/
  47 files checked.
  testMatch:  - 47 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/,/build,/lib/ - 0 matches
  testRegex: (/__tests__/.*|\.(test|spec))\.(tsx?|jsx?)$ - 1 match
Pattern:  - 0 matches
```

Tests are not being executed, what am I doing wrong in here? I've been using the same gitlab-ci.yml config in other projects.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the mistake was in package.json, I was missing <**rootDir**> in **testPathIgnorePatterns** and **modulePathIgnorePatterns** paths under jest options.

```
"testPathIgnorePatterns": [
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
  "<rootDir>/build",
  "<rootDir>/lib/"
],
"modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
  "<rootDir>/dist/",
  "<rootDir>/build/"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is in your path. First open your `cmd` and navigate to directory where your `package.json` resides and then make sure whatever path you have provided in `package.json`, it must get-able.

You can also try to hard-code the path. Once you are able to run it then go for regex.

```
package.json

"name": "test",
"jest": {
        "transform": {},
        "verbose": true,
        "bail": true,
        "testMatch": ["path"]
   },
```

For more details: [testPathIgnorePatterns](https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#modulepathignorepatterns-array-string), [modulePathIgnorePatterns](https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#modulepathignorepatterns-array-string)

```
"testPathIgnorePatterns": [
  "<rootDir>/build"
],
"modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
  "<rootDir>/build/"
]
```